# ffmpeg how to remove all but 2 subtitles without knowing their index number

Tags: ffmpeg, video

Let's say I got one of thouse movies that came with 20 or 30 subtitles. How to remove all subtitles of a movie except English and Portuguese, but I don't know there index number.

If I would know the index number I could something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map_metadata -1 -map 0:s:5 -map 0:s:14 -c copy output.mkv
```

But I don't know the index number and I would like to apply something to a whole folder.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-map` accepts metadata specifiers i.e.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s:m:language:eng -map 0:s:m:language:por output.mkv
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted.